# Is there a boilerplate text to avoid legal liability for the content of a book?

Tags: disclaimers

I am self-publishing a book on CreateSpace. The appendix contains some forms that readers are welcome to print out and use in their workplace. Although I don't offer any recommendation or description for how they are to be used, readers might assume that these documents could potentially protect someone from being wrongfully fired, or would be presented as records in a court case.

Is there any standard boilerplate legal text that I can place in the front of my book that blanket protects me from any legal liability for the contents of my book?

Answer (score 3):

You could include a notice that the forms are not legal advice, and you make no guarantees on their effects in particular situations, and that readers should use them at their own risk, and that they are provided "as is" with no warranties of any kind. You might also find websites that offer downloadable legal forms, or forms similar to the ones you intend to create, and see what disclaimers or waivers of liability such sites typically include.

I am not a lawyer, and this is not legal advice.